# Detect when switched to an audio only HLS Stream

Tags: ios, video, avaudioplayer, http-live-streaming

In our app, we have an HLS index file which contains multiple HLS streams for different Bandwidths. Our Lowest Badwidth stream is only audio.

We want to show a message to our users when the app has degraded to the Audio Only stream.

Is there a way to detect when we have switched to an audio only stream?

Thanks!